# asp.net：server.transfer後のurl（？）の取得方法

Tags: asp.net

恐れ入ります。
asp.netのServer.Transferでページ遷移をしていますが
**Transfer後に”自分”のURL**はどこで取得できるでしょうか？
つまり

```
Server.Transfer("/dirA/page1.aspx")
```

で遷移したページ/dirA/page1.aspxで自分のURL「/dirA/page1.aspx」を”動的”に知りたい
という間抜けな話です。

ちなみに、以下

```
Page.PreviousPage.Request.Url
Page.Request.Url
```

いずれもTransfer前のURIですね。

**Transfer前にどこかに”わざわざ”保存**しておかないと
”自分”のURLすらも取れないのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Server.Transfer()`メソッド](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/y4k58xk7(v=vs.110).aspx)はブラウザーに対して元のURLのまま、返すコンテンツを切り替えるものですから

> いずれもTransfer前のURIですね

は当然の結果ですし

> **Transfer前にどこかに”わざわざ”保存**しておかないと”自分”のURLすらも取れないのでしょうか。

正しく自分のURLが取得できています。

`Transfer()`後、処理しているURLを取得するには[`Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath`プロパティ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.web.httprequest.currentexecutionfilepath(v=vs.110).aspx)を使用します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました。感謝です。m(_ _)m

Answer (score 0):

これが最善であるかは分かりませんが、`Page.GetType().FullName`で

> ASP.dir1_page1_aspx

という物理パスに基づいた型名が参照できます。ですので

```
GetType().FullName.Substring(4).Replace("_aspx", ".aspx").Replace('_', '\\')
```

の要領で変換できます。ただし元から`_`が含まれているような場合は特別な考慮が必要です。

また状況によっては`GetType().BaseType.FullName`の名称を使用したほうが良いかもしれません。こちらは各ASPXファイルの`Inherits`属性に記述されている値が取得できますが、変更可能ですので実際のディレクトリー構成とは一致していない可能性があります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathでできたので試してませんが、ご回答感謝です。(^o^)/